# ANT & JAXB: add "extension" and make generated classes "serializable"

Tags: java, serialization, ant, jaxb

this is my first post in this great community.

I am trying to generate beans classes using JAXB and Ant

This is my code:

```
    <target name="generation beans" description="generation des beans depuis un schema" depends="init">
    <echo message="generation des beans depuis un schema" />

    <exec executable="${javahome}/bin/xjc"  >


        <arg value="-d" />
        <arg value="${sources}" />
        <arg value="-p" />
        <arg value="metier" />
        <arg value="Player.xsd" />      
    </exec>
</target>
```

It works well but i want to add "Extension" and make the generated classes serializable.
Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the following:

```
 <target name="generation beans" description="generation des beans depuis un schema" depends="init">
    <echo message="generation des beans depuis un schema" />

    <exec executable="${javahome}/bin/xjc"  >
        <arg value="-extension" />
        <arg value="-b" />
        <arg value="binding.xml" />
        <arg value="-d" />
        <arg value="${sources}" />
        <arg value="-p" />
        <arg value="metier" />
        <arg value="Player.xsd" />      
    </exec>
</target>
```

Where `binding.xml` is:

```
<jxb:bindings 
    xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
    jxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc"
    version="2.1">


    <jxb:globalBindings>
        <xjc:serializable/>
    </jxb:globalBindings>

</jxb:bindings>
```